# Ember Components Observers attribute

Tags: ember.js

I have upgraded to the latest version of ember. I noticed a potential issue that when a component function which observes an outercontext attribute it is actually initialized even before the actual component is initialized.

**$ember version**

```
version: 1.13.1
node: 0.12.6
npm: 2.12.1
```

To demonstrate I have the following hbs which inserts the test-component:

```
{{test-component parentController=controller}}
```

**Previous version of ember**

test-component.js

```
feedLoadedChanged: function(){
        var self = this;
        alert("feedLoadedChanged and self initialized" + self.get('parentController').get('feedLoaded'));
}.observes('parentController.feedLoaded'),
```

In the previous versions of ember the above alert used to work successfully. However in the current version of ember the **self/this** variable referred to the Window object and NOT the component.

So I thought this was due the feedLoadedChanged function being initialized before the component it self was initialized.

**Current version of ember**

For the current version of ember I made the following changes. The didInsertElement captures the self component into the variable _self and the original alert function is only called if that variable exist.

The code below fixes the issue:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
            var self = this;
            self.set('_self', this);
    },

    feedLoadedChanged: function(){
     var self = this.get('_self');
        alert('feedLoadedChanged');
     if(self){
        alert("feedLoadedChanged and self initalized" + self.get('parentController').get('feedLoaded'));
     } else {
        alert("feedLoadedChanged and self NOT initalized");
     }
}.observes('parentController.feedLoaded')
});
```

This is the sequence of alerts which occurrs during application loaded.

1. feedLoadedChanged
2. feedLoadedChanged and self NOT initalized
3. feedLoadedChanged
4. feedLoadedChanged and self initalizedtrue (this is the original alert)

So I am wondering if this initialization of the component function before the component it self is an issue or expected behaviour ?

Comment: FYI I have raised this as a bug https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11719 . However it has been suggested that I use the new component lifecycle hooks: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html . To solve the issue. Will provide a proper answer soon

Comment: the component hooks look like a great way to get some fine grain control. (not privy on them myself though). Also a couple things to point out from your example. `.observes` is not recommended but if you really need an observer. setting observers up manually is (only slightly) better. e.g. inside `init` hook `this.addObserver()`. also `self.get('parentController').get('feedLoaded')` is equivalent to `self.get('parentController.feedLoaded')` :) cheers

Comment: Thanks Joel. Implemented your suggestion as per below :)

Comment: yeah, that's totally a bug

Comment: cool @ShivamSinha ! glad it helped. Also, keeping inventory of the observers in a single hook is nicer than using the `.observes` function prototypes (e.g. `function () {}.observes()` ) because it helps keep an easy to read list of observers that you've manually set up :) since observers unexpectedly firing off can be a pain point, it's nice to be aware up front where observers are

Comment: Cheers Joe. Since your suggestions have been the most benefitical could you please copy my answer below add the prototypes example and I'll accept your answer and delete mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the didInsertElement lifecycle method combined with the manual addObserver as suggested by Joel has resolve the issue.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
         this.addObserver('parentController.feedLoaded',this,'feedLoadedChanged');
    }

    feedLoadedChanged: function(){
     alert("feedLoadedChanged and self initalized"  + this.get('parentController.feedLoaded'));
    }
});
```